# (Wordpress Multisite) Limit function to given sites

Tags: php, wordpress, function, multisite

I have a little problem with my website, sorry for my noobish question, but I really can't solve the issue:
How can I, using multisite, limit a function to only given site? I use such function to adapt homepage regarding user state:

```
    function switch_homepage() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $page = 4284; // for logged in users
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    } else {
        $page = 4133; // for logged out users
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    }
}
```

I want the code to just work on a main site. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if the current site is the main site with this code:

```
    if ( is_main_site() ) {
        // Do stuff only for the main site
    }
```

Another option is to add your code in a plugin and then activate the plugin only on the main site.

Comment: Nikolay, can I also use similar function to display given page if given day is for example tuesday?

Comment: @KamilTheJungleZabiegaa I am only going to answer about checking the day here (you should start a new thread, and send me the url here if you want). First, keep in mind that the week day depends on the time zone. So in this example it will check based on the chosen time zone in the general settings in the current site in WordPress: function get_wp_week_day_number() { return get_date_from_gmt( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time() ), 'w' ); } if ( get_wp_week_day_number() == 2 ) { /* do stuff only on Tuesday */ }

Comment: Thanks, I created a full thread to solve this. Here is the url: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217875/wordpress-multisite-display-page-as-homepage-in-chosen-weekdays)